# delete multiple rows from different tables on oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a two table.One of them is student, the other one is salary.

Student table

```
  id  | name   | code | status
  1   | steven | 123  | 100
  2   | joe    | 678  | 200
  3   | paul   | 758  | 100
```

Salary table

```
 id  | code | status |  currency
  1   | 123  | 100    |  euro
  2   | 678  | 200    |  dolar
  3   | 758  | 520    |  yuan
```

I want to delete row1 from Student table and row 1 and 2 from Salary table because code and status fields
are same.

I write that query

```
delete a,b Student as a , join Salary as b  
on a.code= b.code and a.status = b.status
```

but it is not working.I want to delete rows with one query.Do you have any idea?

Comment: AFAIK Oracle has no DELETE JOIN syntax.

Comment: Check out ON DELETE CASCADE foreign keys.

Comment: Wait a minute. How is student 1 (Steven) related to row with ID = 2 in SALARY table whose CODE = 678 and STATUS = 200? True, they exist in STUDENT table, but there's no other relation whatsoever. Does it mean that regardless of which row you delete from the STUDENT table, you want to delete all rows in SALARY whose (CODE, STATUS) combination exists in STUDENT? That doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: I want to delete rows that have same code and status values from tables

Comment: Is it possible to have any code in salary table which is not available in student table?

Comment: "I want to delete rows that have same code and status values from tables" - OK. How does your "I want to delete row1 from Student table and row 1 and 2 from Salary" come into play? Why don't you want to delete rows 1 **and 2** from the STUDENT table, then?

Comment: I dont want to see rows that have same code and status fields on that tables.Only one table should have it

Comment: _"I want to delete row1 from Student table and row 1 and 2 from Salary table because code and status fields are same."_   So why not row 2 from salary?   And please help us to help you by reading and heeding https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would something like this do? PL/SQL, though, not SQL.

Initial data sets:

```
SQL> select * from student;

        ID NAME         CODE     STATUS
---------- ------ ---------- ----------
         1 steven        123        100
         2 joe           678        200
         3 paul          758        100

SQL> select * from salary;

        ID       CODE     STATUS CURREN
---------- ---------- ---------- ------
         1        123        100 euro
         2        678        200 dollar
         3        758        520 yuan
```

Remove common `(CODE, STATUS)` combinations:

```
SQL> begin
  2    for cur_r in (select code, status from student
  3                  intersect
  4                  select code, status from salary
  5                 )
  6    loop
  7      delete from student where code = cur_r.code and status = cur_r.status;
  8      delete from salary  where code = cur_r.code and status = cur_r.status;
  9    end loop;
 10  end;
 11  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Result:

```
SQL> select * from student;

        ID NAME         CODE     STATUS
---------- ------ ---------- ----------
         3 paul          758        100

SQL> select * from salary;

        ID       CODE     STATUS CURREN
---------- ---------- ---------- ------
         3        758        520 yuan

SQL>
```

Comment: Thank you very much.That is exactly what i want

Answer (score 0):

You can use two statements to do so easily:

```
delete student s where exists(
select * from student stu inner join salary sal on stu.code=sal.code and stu.status=sal.status and stu.id=s.id);

delete salary sal where not exists (select code from student stu where stu.code=sal.code);
```

First one to delete all the students having same code and status in both tables and second is to delete all the rows from salary table where code doesn't exist in student table.